# Unable to vary speed for a 2 wire BLDC motor

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have a 2 wire BLDC motor (UNMS 020KPDC-B), when I hook up directly to the voltage supply and vary the range between 2.7V and 6V, the speed changes. I purchased a TB6612FNG kit and hooked it up to the Arduino's digital PWM signal and potentiometer and I can see that the voltage varies, but the motor doesn't actually turn on until it reaches the pump's 6V nominal voltage. I have also tried a transistor/mosfet controller and it still doesn't work. Why is that? How would I be able to vary the voltage on this pump?

Comment: Are you using a scope or a meter to view the voltage?

Comment: This BLDC version contains active electronics to generate the internal BLDC signals. I think is is not possible to feed this with a PWM modulated supply. An L/C low pass filter between PWM and motor may have a chance.